# How to execute python script which expects command line args by bash script?

Tags: python, bash

I have oracle's `wlst.sh` bash script that invokes a python script. This python script expects command line arguments.

```
/somewhere/oracle/Middleware/wlsserver_10.3/common/bin/wlst.sh /path/foo.py -a aaa -b bbb
```

I realized that it only executes `wlst.sh` but not the `foo.py` if I pass the command line arguments. If I don't pass command line args then `foo.py` is executed. I tried to wrap entire python script calling with `double-quote` that didn't do a trick. What would be correct syntax I can use?

Update:

`wlst.sh` is the given script from oracle suite. Here is `foo.py`. I don't do anything with passed in parameters for now. If I keep `connectToAdmin()` only without passing any parameters then `print "Successfully connected"` is printed however if I include `main(sys.argv)` method then `foo.py` is never executed.

```
import sys, getopt

def usage():
   print "usage: foo.py -a aaa -b bbb"
   sys.exit(2)

def connectToAdmin():  
  try:
    connect(<username>,<passwd>,"t3://fooServer:<port>")
    print "Successfully connected"    
  except WLSTException, we:
    print "Unable to connect to administration server.."
    sys.exit(2)

# Parse command line arguments
def main(argv):   
   unixOptions = "ha:b:"
   gnuOptions = ["help","bar","boo"]   
   boo = ""
   bar = ""
   try:
      opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv[1:], unixOptions, gnuOptions)
   except getopt.GetoptError, err:
      print str(err)
      usage()                  
   for o, a in opts:
      if o in ("-h", "--help"):
         usage()         
      elif o in ("-a", "--bar"):
         boo = a                 
      elif o in ("-b", "--boo"):
         bar = a

   connectToAdmin()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Check this. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24491/using_wlst.htm#i1080500

Comment: How are we supposed to answer this if we know the Python script's contents but not that of the bash script?

Comment: ...now, a *correctly written* bash script designed as a wrapper will use `"$@"` to treat its exact `argv` as a command, after `shift`ing off any arguments meant for its own consumption; but I don't trust Oracle to do anything correctly; they don't exactly have a history of following good practices in and around the UNIX ecosystem.

Comment: ...anyhow, for a question to be on-topic here, it needs to have a [mre] -- the shortest possible code that's complete enough to reproduce the error and test a proposed fix -- included in the question itself. If you can build a cut-down representation of whatever the Oracle script is doing to include in the question (obvs., sufficiently cut down as to no longer be copyright-infringing) that demonstrates the problem, we might have something answerable; right now, we don't.

Comment: Joao, ty for the link. I assume python script has to read a text file contains command line args.

Comment: Charles, I agree with you. All I know is I have to rely on `wlst.sh` script to connect to admin server which it does via `foo.py` however I wanted to pass extra data via cmd line args to be consumed later on once the connection is made. I wasn't sure how to pass them but it looks Joao answered my question. Ty for your time.

Comment: @DaeYoung Yes, but the doc's also said you must use Jython not python. `You use script files with the Jython commands for running scripts.